# Inset spacing default setting for text frame InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, creative-cloud

Whenever I create a new text frame it creates inset spacing as a default and I have to keep removing it. I am not sure why, I have made some text boxes within the document have inset spacing and maybe its remembering that, its not part of any character or paragraph styles I made and I tried creating a text box with no paragraph or character styles and it still creates a text frame with inset spacing.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **no document open** choose `Object > Text Frame Options..` and alter the settings however you'd like.

This will cause all ***new*** documents to use this setting.

It *won't* change existing documents. Meaning, if you've adjusted the Text Frame Options with a document *open*, that document will retain whatever settings were applied.

---

Many InDesign settings can be adjusted this way - with no document open - and then all *new* documents conform to those settings.